# Inverting the normalized Gaussian to get a kernel window radius

Tags: filters, gaussian, window, kernel, gaussian-kernel

I am seeking to compute a kernel radius to use with my gaussian convolution filter, and inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/68050503/, I came up with:

$$r=\sqrt{-2\sigma^2\ln\left( \epsilon\sigma\sqrt{2\pi} \right)}$$

This is basically inverting the normalized gaussian, setting $g(x,\sigma)=\epsilon$ and solving for $x$ given $\sigma$ and $\epsilon$.

However, I noticed that with $\epsilon=0.01$ at about $\sigma>22$ my kernel radius computation started get *smaller* instead of bigger, and at $\sigma>40$ it went completely undefined (`NaN`).

So I re-derived this little formula (derivation at bottom) and graphed it in desmos, and mysteriously, it indeed showed a graph that peaked at about $20$ and fell to $0$ at about $40$ and was thereafter was undefined!

[image: Screenshot of graph in desmos; peaks at about 25ish, falls to zero at about 40ish, and goes undefined after that!]

Here is the desmos graph, with multiple steps through the derivation, all showing the same graph (only the first is activated though): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ucrqzrahxs

**Where is my math wrong?**

---

Derivation:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
g(x,\sigma)&=&\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}}
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Normalized Guassian function.}\\
g(r,\sigma)&=&\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}}
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Set radius to x.} \\
\epsilon&=&g(r,\sigma)
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Set }\epsilon\text{ to output} \\
\epsilon&=&\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}}
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Replace }g(r,\sigma). \\
\ln \epsilon&=& \ln \left[\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-r^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right]
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Log both sides.} \\
\ln \epsilon&=& \ln \left[\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \right]-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Get rid of }e. \\
\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2} + \ln \epsilon&=& \ln \left[\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \right]
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Move x to the left hand side.} \\
\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}&=& \ln \left[\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \right] - \ln \epsilon
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Move }\epsilon\text{ to the right hand side.} \\
\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}&=& \ln \left[\frac{1}{\epsilon\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \right]
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Move }\epsilon\text{ into the log function.} \\
r^2&=& 2\sigma^2\ln \left[\frac{1}{\epsilon\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \right]
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Move the denominator to the right.} \\
r  &=& \sqrt{2\sigma^2\ln \left[\frac{1}{\epsilon\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \right]}
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Square root both sides.} \\
r  &=& \sqrt{-2\sigma^2\ln \left[\epsilon\sigma\sqrt{2\pi} \right]}
  &\hspace{5em}\text{Flip the fraction inside the logarithm.} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be correct, because when $\sigma$ increases, the peak of the Gaussian curve becomes smaller and eventually less than 0.01.

Edit: Indeed, this is the curve for $\sigma=39$ (red) and for $\sigma=41$ (blue). The latter stays below 0.01

[image]

Comment: ~~Any better idea on how to approximate a kernel radius?~~ I'll just use 3x sigma as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: 3$\sigma$ is usually a good guess, but it really depends what you need it for. Otherwise you can retry your approach using $g(x,\sigma)/g(0,\sigma)=\epsilon$